# Adding extra column for MIN value on each row in excel sheet from python

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, excel-formula

I have a python program which gets data and writes to a excel file , however i would like to add at then end of each row a formula that gets the MIN value of all numbers from column C to column CM therefore the MIN of that will be written in column CO here I have an image of what I would like it to be like ,

[The Min function is in the CO column click here for image (this was done by manually using the MIN function)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzRfW.png)

My current code is as follows

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

players = []

def get_name(td):
    return td.find('b').text

def get_id(td):
    links = td.find_all('a')
    link = links[0]['href']
    link = link.split('/')
    return link[5]

def get_ovr(ovr):
    return ovr.text

def read_page(pageId):
    link = 'https://www.futwiz.com/en/fifa21/players?page=' + str(pageId) + '&release=icons'
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    ovrList = soup.find_all('div', {'class', 'otherversion21-txt'})
    td = soup.find_all('td', {'class', 'player'})
    for i in range(0, len(ovrList)):
        player = {
            'name': get_name(td[i + 1]),
            'id': get_id(td[i + 1]),
            'ovr': get_ovr(ovrList[i])
        }
        players.append(player)

def get_prices(playerId):
    link = 'https://www.futwiz.com/en/app/price_history_player21?p=' + str(playerId) + '&c=xb'
    r = requests.get(link)
    pricePageText = r.text
    pricePageText = pricePageText.replace('[', '')
    pricePageText = pricePageText.replace(']', '')
    pricePageText = pricePageText.split(',')
    prices = []
    for i in range(len(pricePageText)):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            prices.append(pricePageText[i])
    return prices


for pageId in range(0, 13):
    print('Reading page: ' + str(pageId+1))
    read_page(pageId)

f = open('newData.csv', 'w', newline='')
with f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for player in players:
        print('Read player: ' + player['name'])
        prices = get_prices(player['id'])
        profile = [player['name'], player['ovr']]

        #To download all numbers, uncomment following line and comment (1) line
        profile.extend(prices)

        #To download only last number
       # profile.append(prices[len(prices) - 1]) #(1) Line

        writer.writerow(profile)
```

any help would be appreciated thanks in advance hope its not too confusing

Comment: How are you opening the data? By doubble clicking the csv file or do you load the data of the csv file into your excel workbook?

Comment: double clicking on file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it's a requirement to get the minimum value within the Python script or it's also acceptable to just have it in your Excel workbook. If it's not required that the python script calculates the min: the following solution can be used:

Create a new .xlsx file > Click on the data tab in the ribbon and select Get data from file from csv. see the picture below:
[image: get data from file]

Select the .csv file that your python script has created. and click on transforming data. The Power Query editor will pop up, here is where you can automate to add a column that has the minum value. Do this by selecting the column that participate in the min (column C to CM), select multiple columns by holding ctrl and click on the column name.

If all columns are selected: click on the 'add column tab', click on statistics and choose 'Minimum'. Also change the name of the column if desired. Now that the column is created you can click on the 'Home' tab and close and load the data.

The result: Run your python script, open the excel file, click on refresh data in the data tab and you will have your dataset with a minimum column.

Let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

,Jimmy

Comment: You're welcome, go get those cheap players on the FUT market lol :)